# How to make msysgit installation a remote repository

Tags: git, installation, msysgit

In my development environment at home I want to install msysgit im my
local machine and in a server that I have.

The goal is to develop in my local machine and then pushing it to the
server (remote repository), for the nightly builds.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to config the server's msysgit
installation to be a remote repository. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply share a .git repository over windows filesharing, having the share mounted (assigned a drive letter). That way you can also control access by the normal sharing permissions etc, and approach the repo as you'd do with a remote file based repository.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want your remote repository in a windows machine.

The easiest way to share a bare git repository in windows is using cygwin. You install sshd deamon and the git packages and you configure some users and you can start pushing to the remote repository.

Maybe you can try to install [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) in the server machine is you have many repositories and users to share the repositories.

Comment: Yes, I want a remote repository in a windows machine. But I would like to know if it's possible to use msysgit for that...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to share the repository and map it to the local machine, then you could push to it just like to another local repository.

Another solution would be to serve the remote repository through an Webdav enabled HTTP server (Apache should work ok).

For other solutions, see the **Setting up Git server** section on my blog: [Git resources](http://asimilatorul.com/adapter/post/git-resources/)